# Delete all files inside a directory over FTP with BASH

Tags: linux, bash, ftp

I try to delete all files from a directory on a remote FTP server with BASH. I was only able to delete the files and the folder, but not just clearing a folder out.. :/

Comment: `rm -rf *` didn't work?

Comment: Are you using an FTP client to access the remote system or SSH.  Bash is simply a shell, but bash isn't used via an FTP client.

Comment: rm -rf * would work on local systems, but I have to delete the files over ftp (there is no ssh). I thought to use lftp or ncftp but I am not sure which one to choose. Thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

From the `ftp` man page:

> mdelete [remote-files] Delete the remote-files on the remote machine.

So you should be able to connect to your ftp server, navigate to the proper directory, and then `mdelete` the desired files:

```
ftp nobody@ftp.example.com
cd my_local_directory
prompt
mdelete *.txt~
```

The `prompt` command tells your ftp client not to ask you for a confirm each time.