# FTP commands from BASH. what does ~ do?

Tags: linux, bash, ftp

I was trying to delete multiple files from FTP using Bash.

Then I found my answer [here](https://superuser.com/questions/452556/delete-all-files-inside-a-directory-over-ftp-with-bash) with using the `prompt` command.

But I want to know what the tilde ~ does in:

```
ftp nobody@ftp.example.com
cd my_local_directory
prompt
mdelete *.txt~
```

I found this [site](http://www.wmld.com/tech/ftpashtmlserv.html) which says that:

With some ftp servers, the "tilde" character, or ~ is used preceeding a username to bypass the need to specify the full path to the user's directory. For example,

my_university.edu/users/bob/welcome.html

might also be reached by specifying:

my_university.edu/~bob/welcome.html

But that's relevant to this use case.

Comment: It's just part of the file name. Some text editors append it for the previous version of a file after editing.

Comment: I've posted an answer, so others can see immediately that it is solved.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `~` character has no special meaning in FTP, and in your example it is simply part of the file name.

Several text editors (including `gedit`) append `~` to the name of a file when it is updated, so the `~` copy becomes the previous version. Other text editors have different back-up naming schemes.